# Как правильно отдать `404 Page Not found` ?

Tags: http-status-code-404, .htaccess, php, http

Привет, такое ощущение что в 404 нужен специальный хеадер какой то, как бы Яндекс от меня его потребовал. Ситуация такая:

```
###### .htaccess ######

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* route.php [L]

###### route.php ######

// парсится урл, проверочки туда сюда
if (file_exists($exe_mod_file)) { Include_once($exe_mod_file); }
else { Include_once (Q_PATH . '/mods/404.php'); } // тут обрабатывается случаи с 404

###### 404.php ######

<?php
header('что то нужно написать чтобы бот знал что это ошибка 404 и такого файла\страницы\каталога нет');
?>

echo '<h1>404 Error</h1><a href="anylink/">Any advert links</a>';
```

Вот примерно привёл структуру как работает, подскажите что прописать в хедере чтобы яндекс-бот\браузер\любой клиент знал что страница не существует. А нето скажем любой запрос даже типа

```
http://mydomain.org/kfj&UHJdkeh478hrtnfjirednrfjngjngf.jpg
```

Отдаётся как 200, что не очень допустимо :( спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё оказалось очень просто!